# SQL query BETWEEN incorrect result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database of startups, each startup has a total_funding field. I need to be able to search startup in the range of total_funding, for example, I am running those queries

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS total 
  FROM organization 
 WHERE 1 
   AND (organization.total_funding_usd BETWEEN 0 AND 1000000) 
 total : 931728

 SELECT COUNT(*) AS total 
  FROM organization 
 WHERE 1 
   AND (organization.total_funding_usd BETWEEN 1000000 AND 5000000) 
 total : 32415

SELECT COUNT(*) AS total 
  FROM organization 
 WHERE 1 
   AND (organization.total_funding_usd BETWEEN 0 AND 5000000) 
 total : 957721
```

The problem is if I add the results of the first two queries I am getting 931728 + 32415 = 964 143 and this is not equal to the result of the third query that is equal to 961 974

Does anyone have an idea why I am missing 2169 startups?

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: That says that 2170 rows have funding of exactly 1 million.  (Gordon elaborates on what you should do to avoid quandaries like this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between includes the end points.  I suspect you want:

```
WHERE organization.total_funding_usd >= 0 AND
      organization.total_funding_usd < 1000000

WHERE organization.total_funding_usd >= 1000000 AND
      organization.total_funding_usd < 5000000

WHERE organization.total_funding_usd >= 0 AND
      organization.total_funding_usd < 5000000
```

In other words, organizations with total funding of 1000000 are counted twice.

Comment: @squillman . . . No.  I am intentionally leaving the larger amount open for all the intervals.  The code is more consistent that way.

Comment: Ok, I understand from an extensibility point.  Was just that the OP had that endpoint in the question.